# Disappointed User

Tags: discussion

Saw this comment in user page of [Rachel](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/1130/rachel),

> I'm done with this site unless something changes. I feel its changed
>   too far from the original programming resource it once was, and the
>   current moderation style is not for me.
>
> I dislike that so much valuable information gets deleted for the sake
>   of "maintaining a clean site", dislike the way many users are treated
>   (particularly new ones), and dislike the way the overall culture of
>   this site has been changing from a community of programmers out to
>   teach and learn from each other, to an insular group of programming
>   elitists (of course this isn't all of you, or probably even most of
>   you. Its just a large percentage of the more active/vocal users who
>   take part in running the site).
>
> Anyways, I'm not interested in helping to support this site anymore,
>   although I will be happy to take part in any initiatives to changes
>   things.
>
> Also, if someone makes a Q&A site for Programmers to ask questions and
>   get answers from other Programmers about any issue related to their
>   career choice or self-identity as a programmer, let me know. I'd love
>   to participate in such a site again, and will help you promote it.

Thought this needs some attention of active users of the site.  :)

Comment: What kind of attention do you think this should get? Rachel disagrees with the direction of the site, and has every right to do so. Her profile about box is her own and she can write anything she likes in it, as can anyone else (within certain common sense limits of course).

Comment: Thanks for bringing it up but we are all very aware of Rachel's stance, she made it well known on Meta with several discussions regarding this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thank you for the concern however that's a fairly old comment that I added a year ago or so when I realized the site had changed dramatically from it's original scope and purpose ([site history here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3412/1130)), and stopped participating in the main site.

The change caused a number of users to leave the site or delete their accounts, however I didn't want to delete my account since I still use some of the content I posted here, and value being able to see some of the other great deleted content on this site. I also thought that having over 10k rep would be a benefit if things started to change, as I could view deleted content, edit, and vote to reopen.

But I also didn't want to be seen as endorsing the changes SE made to the site (I was on the top page of users at the time), so I just added my opinion to my profile page instead to make it clear I didn't agree with the change in the site's direction.

So I guess what I'm trying to say is that's an old comment regarding some old changes done to the site, and the mods are quite aware of my opinion (and other user's opinions) on the changes that were made, however Stack Exchange decided to proceed with those changes anyways as they thought the benefits it provided outweighed the negatives.

Comment: +1 While I (strongly) disagree with your opinions on the site's direction, your about box is your own and it's the perfect place to share those opinions. Could you do me a small favour and change the "Its" in the last sentence of the second paragraph to "It's"? (OCD, can't help it, sorry)

Comment: @YannisRizos Sure, I didn't know you read my profile enough to care ;)

Comment: @Rachel It would be nice to see someone make a good programmers Q&A site with more reasonable moderation. The fundamental problem here is the flippant attitude towards question askers and the complete lack of respect for their time investment.