# Is there a StackExchange site that would be appropriate for CS career questions?

Tags: discussion

It looks like many programming career questions are posted on this StackExchange site and promptly frozen. Is there an appropriate place for them within the StackExchange network yet?

Answer (score 1):

Career advice is difficult because it is so individualized and time sensitive. We recommend that you ask such questions in our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard). The Workplace.SE caters to some career related issues but has similar strictures on individualized questions. The doubled edge sword of Stack Exchange is to create an easily Googleable reference for getting expert answers to questions immediately. Career advice tends to fall outside that category as it tends to again, be highly individualized and time-sensitive. We tried allowing that sort of question type at the beginning of Programmers. It didn't go [well](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3412/what-is-the-history-behind-the-site-scope-change-from-npr-to-conceptual-questio).

Chat exists specifically for working through the thornier questions without direct, converging answers. The [Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/21/the-whiteboard)'s activity stats will help you find the best time and day of the week to ask your question.